# Queries flag newly imported attributes as invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and every time after I import data from an MS Excel source, the table attributes are flagged (like a spelling error in MS Word) as invalid although they are indeed valid and the query executes with no errors. If I close Management Studio and open it again it the problem is solved.

I have found that this is not the case when I import data from a MS Access source. I suspect it has to do with the updating of the data dictionary but it is just a guess.

I don't know if there is a work around to solve (what I can only describe as an irritation) this without restarting Management Studio.

Thanks

Cliff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to intellisense. You need to **Refresh Local Cache** of intellisense to remove the red line.

**Shortcut**

Press `CTRL + SHIFT + R` to refresh the intellisence in `SSMS`

or in **SSMS** you can do this

```
GOTO SSSMS -> EDIT -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

[image]